# Preferred way to send a notification from a C# function

Tags: c#, notifications, xamarin

Well I have an async method which returns a true or false, after saving successful retrieval of some data from an API to Database.

Since the data is more we are processing it batch by batch, get the first 100 data save it, continue that until we get all the data.

Now my concern is, I don't really want to wait to complete all this batch by batch saves. As soon as the first batch is retrieved and saved,is there any preferred method to inform the calling function "Ok boss there is some data now in the database, you can use that data now. While I continue to save the rest."

Can you please suggest a preferred method to do so? Not only in async, in normal function also.

Comment: possible duplicate of [C# async/await Progress event on Task<> object](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15408148/c-sharp-async-await-progress-event-on-task-object)

Comment: Thanks I think I will exlplore that.

Comment: If you find it useful, you should drop your question :D

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have used `MessagingCenter`to have `Subscribe` and `Unsubscribe` to send status.