# How to async long process from button

Tags: c#, async-await

Currently I have a button that calls a function and has a processing time of 10-20 secs. Is it possible to have some text like "please wait..." rather than the application getting hang.

Here is button where I call my function:

```
private void btnExec_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            LongProcess();
        }
```

And this is the function that executes too long:

```
 public void LongProcess()
        {
            DataTable table = new DataTable();

            table.Columns.Add("DateTime", typeof(string));
            table.Columns.Add("Mass1", typeof(string));
            table.Columns.Add("Mass2", typeof(string));
            table.Columns.Add("Mass3", typeof(string));               

            Console.WriteLine(startDate.Value);
            Console.WriteLine(endDate.Value);

            decimal v = decimal.Parse("1.6345e-008", NumberStyles.Float);
            var pattern = @"^""\d+/\d+/\d+ \d+:\d+:\d+ (AM|PM)""\s+-?\d+\s+\d+.?\d+e-\d+";
            var regex = new Regex(pattern, RegexOptions.Compiled);

            string[] filePaths = Directory.GetFiles(@"C:\\test\\", "*.txt");

            var results = new List<string>();

            foreach (var file in filePaths)
            {
                var lines = File.ReadLines(file).Where(x => regex.IsMatch(x));
                results.AddRange(lines);
            }

            foreach (var result in results)
            {
                string[] words = (result.ToString()).Split(' ');
                string date = words[0].Substring(1) + " " + words[1];

                DateTime oDate = DateTime.Parse(date);

                if (oDate >= startDate.Value && oDate <= endDate.Value)
                {
                    string[] words2 = (words[2].ToString()).Split('\t');
                    string m1 = words2[2];
                    string m2 = words2[3];
                    string m3 = words2[4];                           
                    table.Rows.Add(new object[] { oDate.ToString(), m1, m2, m3});

            File.WriteAllText(@"C:\\test.csv", sb.ToString());
            Console.WriteLine("Done Parsing");
        }
```

Any suuggestion/comments TIA.

Comment: Is your application ASP.NET or WinForms?

Comment: I think that duplicate is sketchy at best

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The simplest way to do this would be to *offload* the work to a new *Thread*/*Task* and use the *Async Await Pattern*

```
private async void btnExec_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    try
    {
       await Task.Run(() => LongProcess());
       // or
       await Task.Run(LongProcess);
    }
    catch (Exception exception)
    {
       // catch any exceptions, as this method will be unobserved 
       // Console.WriteLine(exception);
    }
}
```

- You will probably want to *catch* any *exceptions* in your click *event* as it's an `async void`. Leaving *exceptions* unobserved like this can cause issues
- If you were worried about thread-pool threads being used, you could use `Task.Factory.StartNew` with the `TaskCreationOptions.LongRunning` option
- You might also want guard against multiple presses
- Lastly, when offloading *CPU bound* work like this, you cannot update the *UI* in certain frameworks (like *Winforms* or *WPF*) without marshalling back to the *UI Context*. See this question for some related information on progress updates [C# async/await Progress event on Task<> object](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15408148/c-sharp-async-await-progress-event-on-task-object)